# Fixing typos using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

For example, if I have example.com/experiments.html and the user types in example.com/experiment.html (no "s"), is it possible to redirect the user to example.com/experiments.html using .htaccess?

Edit: "experiments.html" was just an example, I have a lot of pages that users may type incorrectly. Is there an universal solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An easy way is to use `redirect`

```
Redirect 301 /experiment.html /experiments.html
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `RewriteRule` like this:

```
RewriteRule experiment.html experiments.html [L,R=301]
```

That will do a 301 permanent redirect